# Argument 'NavController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

i get this error when i start the app
this is the controller:

```
myApp
    .controller('NavController',
    ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
        $scope.navClass = function (page) {
            var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'main';
            return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
        };
    }]);
```

and this is the app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp',[
    'ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/',{
                    templateUrl:'views/main.html',
                    controller: 'mainCtrl'
                })
               .when('/team1',{
                        templateUrl:'views/team1.html',
                        controller: 'mainCtrl'
                    })
            }]);
```

and the htmlIndex where i use the contoller:

```
<header>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="NavController">
                    <li ng-class="navClass('home')"><a href='#/'>Home</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="navClass('home')"><a href='#/team1'>team1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

i click the nav buttons nothing happens and in the console i get this error "Argument 'NavController' is not a function, got undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you call controller in a wrong way. It should be called on a app like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('NavController',
['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.navClass = function (page) {
        var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'main';
        return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
    };
}]);
```

Take a look at this fiddle for a complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/q91jozyr/

Comment: made the change you suggested still same problem any suggestions?

Comment: have you checked the jsfiddle link? is working as expected? There I do not get any undefined error. Let me know exactly what does not work

Answer (score 0):

When you define the module with `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])` you need to save the reference in the variable `myApp`to reuse the module, when declaring the controller.

**app.js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

**Alternatively** I suggest to call the controller by reusing the module like this:

**controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('NavController', [ /* etc... */ ]);
```

Note that the module is being reused, if you don't specifiy the dependencies again like `angular.module('myApp')` instead of `angular.module('myApp', [ ])`.

In both cases make sure the module `myApp` is bootstrapped by adding `ng-app="myApp"` to any of the parent elements, e.g. the `<body>`:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: made the change you suggested still same problem any suggestions?

Comment: Try and add ng-app to the `<header>` e.g. or in the `<body>` like so:
   `<body ng-app="myApp">`